# Escaping Characters in Bigquery json_extract() function

Tags: json, google-bigquery

when using **Google's BigQuery**, there's a [function](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/query-reference?hl=en#jsonfunctions) that can extract elements from json strings using jsonPath. For example:

```
SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(data,"$.key.value") AS feature FROM tablename
```

when the json key itself contains a dot,`{"key.value":"value"}` It's not clear how to escape that properly.

this jsonpath [message board question](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/jsonpath/7YvgXWP1_7Y) says that  jsonpath itself supports this format

```
@Test 
public void path_with_bracket_notation() throws Exception { 
    String json = "{\"foo.bar\": {\"key\": \"value\"}}"; 

    Assert.assertEquals("value", JsonPath.read(json, "$.['foo.bar'].key"));
```

However in bigquery this type of espcaping attempts cause `Error: JSONPath parse error` errors.

Comment: i'm not sure double escaping works through the web interface, the query parser, jsonpath and the function. try this example: `SELECT JSON_EXTRACT('{"foo": {"key": "value"}}', '$.foo') AS str,
 JSON_EXTRACT('{"foo.bar": {"key": "value"}}', '$.foo.bar') AS str2;` 
using \\ doesn't pass the parser.

Comment: @NorbertvanNobelen the \ in the question are just Java syntax to create a sample JSON payload, not part of the actual jsonpath itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update, new answer:**

BigQuery's `JSON_EXTRACT` and `JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR` functions now support JSON bracket notation in JSONPath, so the following query works:

```
SELECT JSON_EXTRACT('{"key.value": {"foo": "bar"}}', "$['key.value']")
```

and returns

```
{"foo":"bar"}
```

**Old, now outdated answer:**

Unfortunatelly BigQuery does not support escaping special characters in json path. The workaround would be to use REPLACE function to convert dots to underscores, i.e.

```
SELECT 
  json_extract(
    replace('{"key.value":"value"}',
    'key.value',
    'key_value'),
  '$.key_value')
```

Comment: This is quite a dangerous work-around because it would also replace any "key.value" in the rest of the JSON, effectively (possibly) polluting the payload...

Answer (score 1):

use backtick to escape (it is also used to escape hyphen in project/dataset name)

```
SELECT JSON_VALUE(json_field.`key.value`) AS feature FROM tablename
```