# Escaping special characters in JSON key names why loading into BigQuery or Hive

Tags: json, hive, key, special-characters, google-bigquery

I have a json file with one of the keys containing a special character, "-". JavaScript would not allow it to be used inside names, so does not BigQuery.

{"timestamp":"2016-06-01T00:10:55.307Z","ip":"71.223.x.x","user-id":"5755w33e95f626jyh3d31"}

Loading data into BigQuery (from the UI) I don't see how to reference 'user-id'.

I tried to quote it, escape quotes, place them in square brackets - nothing worked. [This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35843548/escaping-characters-in-bigquery-json-extract-function) suggests it's not allowed. What can I do about it? How JSON is generated is out of my control.

Same thing in Hive.

Comment: In Hive you can use backticks (\`) if your column has characters that are special in SQL. Try with

    SELECT \`user-id\` FROM ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately you cannot load these JSON objects directly into BigQuery (via "bq load" or the web UI's "Create Table" flow), since '-' is not a valid character in field names for a BQ table. In other words, there's no way to create a BQ table whose schema matches this JSON data.

An alternative is to load your JSON data into BQ as an uninterpreted JSON string (i.e., a BQ table with one field of string type) and then run a query to pull out relevant fields to populate a BQ table.

Your input data can probably be loaded without modification by picking an obscure character to be the field delimiter and quote character--something that doesn't exist anywhere in your input data. I'd recommend picking something from the bottom half of this chart:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1#Codepage_layout

Once it's ingested into BQ as a single string column, you can use `JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR` to pull out fields as needed. For example:

```
SELECT
  JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(json, '$.timestamp') timestamp,
  JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(json, '$.ip') ip,
  JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(json, '$.user-id') user_id
FROM
  table
```

Comment: Thanks, that is what I did exactly.