# Issue querying BQ table JSON column name with Hyphen "-"

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I have Native BigQuery table with column data type JSON. JSON field contains column name with hyphen like "transection-id".

```
{"timestamp": "123dse", "header": {"type": "special", "source": "ABCW1", "last-updated": {"comps/com[name=TorontoCA]/properties/property[name=uptime]": "736366474"}, "processing-timestamp": "2021-05-25T21:06:37.090259Z"}, "payload": {"openconfig-system": {"system": {"state": {"uptime": "363637"}}}}}
```

Trying to run query like bellow, column name is "value" that contains above string-

```
select value.timestamp,value.header.source,value.header.source,transaction-id 
from `mydataset.test_table`
```

getting error

> Unrecognized name: data at [1:52]

Seems it don't like "Transection-id" field

Answer (score 2):

Use backticks around that column name

```
select 
  value.timestamp,
  value.header.source,
  `transaction-id` 
from `mydataset.test_table`
```

Answer (score 0):

I cannot find `transaction-id` in the above provided JSON, but I will consider `last-updated` instead with special character

Related: [Escaping Characters in Bigquery json_extract() function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35843548/escaping-characters-in-bigquery-json-extract-function)

For JSON Columns with special characters in fields, support has been added for `JSON_EXTRACT` and `JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR` functions as mentioned in the above answer

If you want to access it directly, enclose the field name within  `['last-update']`. This is another way to parse inside JSON as backticks `` ` `` won't work here

```
SELECT data['last update'] AS last_update FROM <table>
```